# Push Ntification Api for Android

Tags: android, push-notification

i want to develop an application that will receive PUSH notification from
server. what is the best way to do this so that i dont have to write so much
code to implement this. I am looking for any commercial service that can do
this for me. Can you please suggest me some good api or service

Answer (score 2):

Urban Airship (urbanairship.com) provides an API to do this. However I would recommend C2DM.

Comment: can u tell me why you recommend C2DM over Urban Airship. Is it because Urban Airship is not free or some other reason plz tell ?

Comment: Because setting up C2DM is easy. UA in any case will use C2DM I think.

Answer (score 1):

Google's c2dm provides nearly this http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/
Even though there is no official push api supported

Answer (score 1):

Yes, here is a good tutorial with all code you need:

http://blog.boxedice.com/2010/10/07/android-push-notifications-tutorial/

http://tokudu.com/2010/how-to-implement-push-notifications-for-android/

Answer (score 1):

Google's C2DM can do this very neatly. Its available from Android 2.2+. Here is a tutorial on how to do it by Vogella. http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidCloudToDeviceMessaging/article.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control and run the service along side your server, you can try OpenMobster Mobile Cloud platform's push service.

It provides the following functionality

- A platform agnostic Push API (works on Android and iOS)
- Queuing (If you are not available, it will deliver later when the phone comes online)
- Should get you up and running quite fast. (No certificates, device tokens etc etc). Just a secure persistent TCP connection to the OpenMobster server is needed (the framework establishes this when the service is installed on the phone)

For more on the platform you can checkout: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/PushFramework

btw: The platform also supports Device-To-Device messaging between other devices in the systsem (applications could be chat, instant messaging etc)

D2D Framework doc: http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/wiki/D2DPushFramework